# Adding of Mathematica "Play" structures in Mathematica 10

Tags: sound

I try to do some sound manipulation in Mathematica 10, because i can't upgrade to Mathematica 11 with my students license, which i realise would have a lot more to offer for Audio Processing.
However i was wondering how it is possible to add "Play" structures, so that they are played after one another when i want to export them.
Short example:

```
s1 = Play[Sin[f*2*Pi*t], {t, 0, dur}, SampleRate -> 44100]
```

`s2 = Play[Sin[f*4*Pi*t], {t, 0, dur}, SampleRate -> 44100]`

and i want to export s1+s2 to a wav file such that it is played one after another, and not simaltaneously.

Thank you very much in advance!
Hope you all have a nice day,
Thomas!

Comment: What about using single `Play` with a Piecewise function for 2*dur?